# Printing a ruby array with zero formatting

Tags: arrays, ruby, configuration-files, put

I have the following bit of code to make an array of IP addresses and I only print out one that matches a pattern.

```
ip_address = node.network.interfaces.map { |p, f| f[:addresses].keys }.flatten.delete_if{|x| x =~ /(.*):(.*)/ }.grep(/127/)
```

I'm trying to then write that IP address to a config file like this

```
  bind "#{ip_address}:22002 ssl crt /etc/ssl/certs/wildcard.example.com.pem"
```

Output:

```
  bind ["127.0.0.1"]:22002 ssl crt /etc/ssl/certs/wildcard.example.com.pem
```

How could I properly write this value to a file without the quotes and brackets?

```
  bind 127.0.0.1:22002 ssl crt /etc/ssl/certs/wildcard.example.com.pem
```

I've tried gsubbing them out, but that's not working for me.

Comment: `bind "#{ip_address.first}:22002 ssl crt /etc/ssl/certs/wildcard.example.com.pem"`

Comment: That worked thank you!

I was able to get #{puts ip_address} to work in irb, but in reality it didn't which was weird.

Comment: @Brando__ your matching code can probably be improved. Which IP address are you trying to select?

Comment: I'm parsing Chef Ohai data that contains a list of interfaces and part of the giant return is the IP address. What I'm returned is an array like this with one public IP, one private IP with a variable third octet, and the loopback.

["127.0.0.1", "10.0.128.1", "8.8.8.8"]

I always want the address in the form of 10.0.128|129|0.*. In reality what I'm doing is this as my regex.

grep(/10.0.(128|129|0).*/)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/GXkMkEAw

This is how the data return actually looks.

Comment: `.` matches any character, you have to use `\.` or `[.]` to match a literal dot. And `*` is not a wildcard character ether, it means "0 or more times".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get the *"quotes and brackets"* because `grep` returns an array. To fix it, you could either print a single element: (see [mudasobwa's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43201275/printing-a-ruby-array-with-zero-formatting#comment73474824_43201275))

```
bind "#{ip_address.first}:22002 ssl crt /etc/ssl/certs/wildcard.example.com.pem"
```

Or you could change the code to return only the first address matching the pattern:

```
ip_addresses = node.network.interfaces.flat_map { |_, f| f[:addresses].keys }
ip_address = ip_addresses.find { |x| x !~ /(.*):(.*)/ && x =~ /127/ }
```

and print it via:

```
bind "#{ip_address}:22002 ssl crt /etc/ssl/certs/wildcard.example.com.pem"
```

> I always want the address in the form of `10.0.128|129|0.*`. In reality what I'm doing is this as my regex. `grep(/10.0.(128|129|0).*/)`

You have to escape the dots (`\.`) or put them in a character class (`[.]`). Otherwise, a single `.` will match *any character*. Furthermore you should also match the start (`^`) and end (`$`) of the string  to avoid matching `210.0.0.1`. A more solid Regexp could look like this:

```
/^10\.0\.(128|129|0)\.\d{1,3}$/
```

Alternatively, there's Ruby's [`IPAddr`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html):

```
require 'ipaddr'

valid_ips = [
  IPAddr.new('10.0.0.0/24'),
  IPAddr.new('10.0.128.0/24'),
  IPAddr.new('10.0.129.0/24')
]

valid_ips.any? { |net| net.include? '127.0.0.1' }  #=> false
valid_ips.any? { |net| net.include? '10.0.128.1' } #=> true
valid_ips.any? { |net| net.include? '8.8.8.8' }    #=> false
```